# scala : use of braces for a function when the parameter is a predicate

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have done `C/Java/C3/Python/JS` all my life. Since yesterday I am looking at some scala code, now i m super confused about everything..

The snippet goes:

```
// Parse the input file
  val lines = fromTextFile(input)

    // Iterate on every element to generate the keys, and then aggregate it
  val counts = lines.mapFlatten{
        line =>
        val rowSplit = line.split(",",-1)
```

....
      }

the signature of the method [mapFlatten in scoobi api](http://nicta.github.io/scoobi/api/SCOOBI-0.7.2/index.html#com.nicta.scoobi.core.DList) is :

```
def mapFlatten[B](f: (A) ⇒ Iterable[B])(implicit arg0: WireFormat[B]): DList[B]
```

**Why do we call `mapFlatten` with**

- `mapFlatten{`

instead of

- `mapFlatten({`

**Is it because the function is taking a predicate as a paramater?**

in this sense, are **while, else, if** functions too?

Comment: another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553578/why-use-curly-braces-over-parentheses

Comment: I tried the mapFlatten(..) and it seems to be working too. @ThiagoPereira I think the answer to ur link applies to my case. Thanks!

Comment: I will make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer

[Why use curly braces over parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553578/why-use-curly-braces-over-parentheses)

there are cases when you do need to use curl braces(multiline expressions) and cases when you don't.

Indeed, they are all functions that receive functions inside.

In this situation:

```
def mapFlatten[B](f: (A) ⇒ Iterable[B])(implicit arg0: WireFormat[B]): DList[B]
```

You pass a function f:(A) that should result in Iterable[B]

Answer (score 1):

From *Programing in Scala*, Fist Edition, Version 7 (yeah, a little dated):

> In any method invocation in Scala in which you're passing in exactly one argument, you can opt to use curly braces to surround the argument instead of parentheses.

And then later:

> The purpose of this ability ... is to enable client programmers to write function literals between curly braces. This can make the method call feel more like a control abstraction.

Comment: horrible.. just standardize these things already.. :) anyway, thanks for the answer. i had read this smwhere, i couldnT make sense of it.